# Detecting blobs that connects to any other blob, maybe with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, blob

In the image, I connects(has a bridge, binds) to universe, but II and III not.

I need to detect both II and III, also I if possible.

Is it possible with current computer vision libraries?

Or any path, idea that i can use to draw my own algorithm?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but hard to express a generic pre-processing solution without a good bunch of sample images.

One solution could be

frame -> [morphological closing](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html#opening) + [skeletonize](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/) +  [find contours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) (gives all)

frame -> skeletonize + find contours (gives 2 and 3)

difference gives 1 obviously,

and maybe with some addition of [shape matching](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#matchshapes) of those contours with an hand-written eye-like contour -just for an extra check.

Comment: Thanks, I look at the morphological closing link, and i think morphological opening might be more helpful. i can run it and compare to the original and the differences from original image might provide some clue about the blobs. Do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: opening or closing depends on the background. It will work if that "bridge" is not that wide -so that it can be closed. Skeleton helps on coping with (neglecting) outlier contours, like neighbours of 1 and 3. Shape matching also helps on neglecting any other contour than an eye-like one.

Comment: Thanks, key words are very helpful